# what design to follow to create a Datawarehouse

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, data-warehouse

I am working on a project to create a data warehouse. I have been using a third party tool to create OLAP cubes, but the problem is it creates separate staging area for each OLAP cube, while most of my cubes share same source of data. The company decided to make a single data warehouse and then the cubes will source data from this warehouse.

I will be extracting data from different sources, and store them in a database(staging area), then I transform this data to appropriate tables for dimensions and facts and store them in a separate database called Data warehouse, and then I will create Individual cubes by sourcing data from data warehouse.

My concern here is can I make different databases for staging area and database warehouse though they will be on the same server?

Plus what about my data marts do I need to have all data marts into same warehouse or I can have them into different databases, I want to know here about logical and physical separations, and best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've been prescribed something along the lines of the Corporate Information Factory from Bill Inmon's data warehouse solution.

http://www.inmoncif.com/library/cif/

Read EDW as your single data warehouse and Departmental Datamarts as your individual cubes.

You could normalise (and perform much of the transformation) as you load the first data warehouse and use this as your centralised data.

When loading your cubes you could choose from several methods of presenting the data for load. Staging to a new single database as you have described, creating views on top of the central data warehouse to read data from or creating a separate staging area for each cube.

Keep in mind the purpose of separate cubes may be to isolate departments from each other to enable rapid concise developments for individual departments and the purpose of the first central data warehouse may be to reconcile disparate data into one agreeable dataset before using for many reporting purposes.

Speak with the people who decided on your architecture to see what they had in mind or the problems they wanted to solve.

Answer (score -1):

For designing a data warehouse.

1. First we  should know the utility of data warehouse(means what type of report we are going to take from the system)
2. we need to chose schema (STAR or SNOWFLAK)
3. we need to create dimensions of data warehouse.
4. we need to create a fact table where all transactional data will be stored.

Comment: Look at my question once again before you respond.